# What is the difference between the two Doctoral Degrees in South Africa: PhD and Doctor of Literature and Philosophy (D.Lit et. Phil)?

Tags: africa

What is the difference between the two Doctoral Degrees in South Africa: PhD and Doctor of Literature and Philosophy (D.Lit et. Phil)?

Where these degrees equal? What is the history  behind this differentiation?